# Resizing a tableau embed code for a visualization? Dont wanna have to scroll over to see the arrow....to scroll over?

Tags: html, css, embed, tableau-desktop

I have a tableau visualization embed that maybe has 20 different tabs/visualizations within it-all next to teach each (tab by tab).

I've been asked if theres a way to make this easier to navigate, as you have to scroll down, then scroll right at the bottom-in order to see the other at the right (which then is what allows you to scroll over farther).

Does anyone know a possible way to make arrow on the right appear-WITHOUT having to go down and scroll over (its hiding out of view essentially)? I've been trying different formats and can't get it to work. This is the code I have. Obviously different parts with the link were removed here....would anyone possibly know a solution?

How the embed looks when you pull it up (can see the arrow on the left but not on the right unless
[image: ....]

You actually scroll down the embed and scroll over right and then the arrow shows up

[image]

Anyone possibly know a fix?